# Creating all possible combinations given a string against a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations, python-itertools

How would you guys go about creating a combinations given a string?

Example: I have a co worker named john and I would like to see how he would look like when grouped with 3 other co workers.

The amount of people in the company is 136 people.

```
Teammates = ['john', 'lizzy', 'tom', 'sarah', 'tiffany', 'max', 'james', 'alice', 'bob']
```

Expected output:

```
Which co worker?: John

['john', 'lizzy', 'tom', 'sarah',]
['john', 'lizzy', 'tom', 'max']
['john', 'lizzy', 'tom', 'james']
['john', 'lizzy', 'tom', 'alice']
['john', 'lizzy', 'tom', 'bob']
['john', 'tiffany', 'max', 'james']
```

I've tried using itertools permutations. The names I have are stored in a sql db. I tried changing my sql query to prioritize my target co worker and iterate against the other co workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use itertools.combinations for this:

```py
import itertools as it

def teammate_combinations(who, group_size)
    return (x for x in it.combinations(teammates, group_size) if who in x)

teammate_combinations('john', 4)
```

Comment: Thank you Will. It's working as I expected now. I appreciate your help

Comment: If the answer helped you, you should click the checkmark next to it to accept it. Doing so will mark your question as solved. Welcome to StackOverflow.